# How to limit the number of map tasks will be run simultaneously on each DataNode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Env:

- Hadoop 3.0.0
- 1 NameNode, 5 DataNode

I config the setting on `mapred-site.yml` as follow to limit only `3` map tasks running simultaneously：

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>3</value>
    <description>The maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>3</value>
    <description>The maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.</description>
</property>
```

But when I run the TestDFSIO benchmark using the following command, The max actual running  map tasks is `8`, it seems the setting does not work:

```
yarn jar /opt/hadoop-3.0.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce- 
client-jobclient-3.0.0-tests.jar \
TestDFSIO -storagePolicy HOT -write \
-nrFiles 500 -fileSize 1000MB -resFile /tmp/DFSIO-write.out
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By restricting mappers, you're limiting throughput. Are you trying to benchmark something?

Answer (score 2):

That config parameter is from old Hadoop 1.x. As far as I can see you are using 3.0.0. Try this one:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>
```

You should set it in yarn-site.xml on every host that runs a NodeManager.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, These properties no longer exist in YARN(http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/migrating-to-mapreduce-2-on-yarn-for-operators/ say that too),  But it seems that `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` is to set the number of container instead of `map task`. The container includes `map task`, `reduce task`, `ApplicationMaster`

Comment: Is there a way to limit the exact number of `map task` on DataNode.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want the number of mappers to be limited to e.g. 3, but the number of containers to e.g. 6, then no, there is no straightforward way to do it.

Comment: I want to set the exact max number of `map task` and `reduce task` each DataNode can run simultaneously, eg 3 `map task` and 1 `recude task`.

Comment: @Honghe If you limit the maximum resources available for a NodeManager JVM, then set the max resources available for a single YARN container, then you effectively limit the total containers running on that node. You cannot specify map or reduce containers, as far as I know

Comment: After I set the `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` to 3 for each DataNode(checked after DataNode restart), there still have more than 3 (such as 10) `YarnChild` process start to run map task on some DataNode.